# How does cPanel let me freely choose DocumentRoot for vhosts without restarting Apache?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

To avoid Apache restart, [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) is used. But, --in this case-- Apache takes vhost configurations from directory pattern. So, I am not free to choose DocumentRoot directory which doesn't match with selected pattern. For example, if I have set pattern like ...user/www/domain/subdomain, I will have to create directories like the pattern to add a domain/subdomain as vhost.

But, cPanel allows its users to freely choose DocumentRoot for add-on domains & subdomains they add. And, it doesn't restart Apache each time a change is made. Changes are instantaneous too.

What does cPanel exactly do to Apache configurations?
I've guessed that it has to do with the same [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html), but I've given up after few days of brainstorming. Can you please help?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's sending Apache a `USR1` signal, to gracefully restart with no loss of service.  I don't have an install with which to verify, but you should be able to confirm by checking the Apache logs.

Comment: @ShaneMadden You are saying to add vhosts in httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf and then restart Apache with USR1 signal. Do you really think it would work? I think, service will have to lose its state to read configuration file.. think if it has thousands of vhosts (making file big).

Comment: A graceful restart can take as long as it needs to without disrupting service at all.  Again, I'm not certain that this is how it's doing it, but you can easily confirm by checking the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found solution. To avoid restart, I don't need [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) (its always better to think in simple way, first). Apache provides `apachectl` for this task. On Debian 6, its binary was `/usr/sbin/apachectl` with default apt-get based installation. It may vary from system-to-system. If you compile & install Apache from its source, it should be in your control.
Assuming location of `apachectl` binary is in your `PATH` variable, this command does what I need:

```
apachectl graceful
```

It restarts web server without terminating current connections to server. Means, its just like reloading configuration files without restart. I don't know how cPanel exactly does it, but it works.